# How to use re() to extract data from javascript variable using scrapy?

Tags: javascript, python, regex, web-scraping, scrapy

My items.py file goes like this:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class SpiItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    lat = Field()
    lng = Field()
    add = Field()
```

and the spider is:

```
import scrapy
import re

from spi.items import SpiItem

class HdfcSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "hdfc"
    allowed_domains = ["hdfc.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://hdfc.com/branch-locator"]

    def parse(self,response):
        addresses = response.xpath('//script')
        for sel in addresses:
            item = SpiItem()
            item['title'] = sel.xpath('//script[@type="text/javascript"][1]').re('(?<="title":).+(?=")')
            item['lat'] = sel.xpath('//script[@type="text/javascript"][1]').re('(?<="latitude":).+(?=")')
            item['lng'] = sel.xpath('//script[@type="text/javascript"][1]').re('(?<="longitude":).+(?=")')
            item['add'] = sel.xpath('//script[@type="text/javascript"][1]').re('(?<="html":).+(?=")')
            yield item
```

The whole javascript code, on viewing page source, is written inside: `//html/body/table/tbody/tr[348]/td[2]`.

Why is my code not working?
I want to extract just the four fields mentioned in the items file.

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html#parsing-javascript-code

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of extracting field by field using regular expressions, extract the complete `locations` object, load it via [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) and extract the desired data from the Python dictionary you'll get:

```
def parse(self,response):
    pattern = re.compile(r"var locations= ({.*?});", re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
    locations = response.xpath('//script[contains(., "var locations")]/text()').re(pattern)[0]
    locations = json.loads(locations)
    for title, data in locations.iteritems():
        print title
```

Comment: @Aditya first of all, you don't need to loop over the scripts in the first place - there is only one `script` you need to locate. Plus, you are basically searching for `script` tag inside every `script` tag you've found which, logically, results into nothing being scraped.

Comment: @Aditya anyway, I've provided a better and more reliable approach.